# Android Emulator Blank Screen

Tags: android

I am using Android Development Studio 1.0.1. I am trying to run a simple application. But the emulator is showing the same blank screen for long time.

Following is log from program. [image: No change in the screen]

```
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7 Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks emulator: device fd:828 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode creating window 51 69 385 683
```

Comment: Anndroid Emulator is very bad, you better don't use it. Genymotion is much more better than that, download it.

Comment: You should check out this question here to help you speed up the emulator.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-we-can-speed-up-the-android-emulator?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you install the [HAXM software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-we-can-speed-up-the-android-emulator?rq=1) to speed up your existing emulator, or you could download [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download) and use their emulator.

Comment: Uninstalled Android Studio and Installed again. It works. Also Genymotion is also useful .. thank you